# Wysiwyg can't translate image url to real path in editor

Tags: magento2, wysiwyg

Editor after insert image

```
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/test.png"}}" alt="test" />
```

After click button show editor to view image

```
<img src="{{media url=" alt="" />
```

Path image was lost. Found this problem when edit content and insert image in catalog product. How to fix it or anyone can tell me exactly where code/js related to this problem

Using magento 2.1.3

Comment: Double quote is created issue. `<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/test.png"}}" alt="test" />` should be `<img src="{{media url='wysiwyg/test.png'}}" alt="test" />`

Comment: If you see in cms add page content worked with double quote. Magento auto generate quote after insert